# Matching 2 specific regex in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe there's no solution for this.

```
$("input[id^='pricechange']").on("input", function() {
   if (this.value != $("input[id^='rate']")) {

   }
});
```

I have a table that has inputs in the cell, it's dynamic and can have any amount of rows. I'm using regex to pick up any changes to a field: `pricechange123`, `pricechange000`, `pricechange999`, etc. Once a user inputs a value it needs to cross reference it with it's accompanying value in the rates column: `rate123`, `rate000`, and `rate999`. As of now `$("input[id^='rate']")` would pick up all the rates.

Is there a way to tell which id was picked up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside that input handler, it's just `this.id`.

```js
$("input[id^='pricechange']").on("input", function() {
  console.log(this.id);

  // extract the numeric part:
  var myIdNumber = this.id.replace('pricechange', '');
  // so you can use it on the #rate123 element similarly:
  if (this.value != $('#rate' + myIdNumber).value) {
    // ...
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="pricechange1">
<input id="pricechange2">
```

Comment: I'm dumb. Thank you! I'll accept when it lets me! :)

Comment: Not at all, sometimes it's the easiest problems that are the hardest to spot.   (One potential source of confusion is that you aren't using regex here, just the jQuery attribute-starts-with selector -- if you were looking up regex answers that would've led you in the wrong direction)